# How to set value to phonenumber in register.php from the signup.php in Yii2?

Tags: yii2-basic-app

This is my field in signup.php (view file)

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'post','id' => 'form-signup','action' => 'http://localhost/basic1/web/index.php?r=site/reg']);?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'PhoneNumber') ?>
```

How to set value in register.php (view file)

```
<?=$form->field($model,  'PhoneNumber',array('value'=>'<?php echo $_POST['PhoneNumber']';?>)) ?>
```

Is there is any code to include in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. (after submitting signup page).

in **register.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['PhoneNumber']) && !empty($_POST['PhoneNumber'])) // for preventing error
{
    $model->PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
}

<?= $form->field($model, 'PhoneNumber')->textInput(); ?>
```